# how to make horizontal scrolling website?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontal scrolling website and I want the divs to float to the right which I can do. But I don't want to have to define the width of the container because it could be different on different pages.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please note that Stack OverFlow is not a free code-writing service. Please **[edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53969876/edit)** to include your tries. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. I am currently flagging this question for No MCVE.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
body {
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

as you can see:

```css
body {
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

.cont {
  display:flex;
}

.cont div {
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  background:pink;
  border:1px solid #000;
  flex-shrink:0;
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```